# Can I view a channel's subscribers on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

YouTube just recently changed its channel design and I really like being able to see all the subscribers to a channel. Is it possible to view a channel's subscribers? (Note: I'm *not* talking about my own channel, I'm referring to any channel that I don't own.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say so, but no. You cannot see the subscribers of a particular channel. You can only see the number of subscribers to a channel.

Even if the channel owner wants everyone to see their subscribers list, there is nothing he/she can do about it.